# jQuery- How to change the select value depending upon the result returned via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a select options

```
<select id= 'abc'>
    <option val=1>a</option>
    <option val=2>b</option>

</select>
```

I'm calling an Ajax function and returning a result. If result is 1, then option `a` should be selected automatically, else `b` should be selected.

This is what I'm doing.

```
if (result == 1){
    $("#abc").val('1')
}
else  $("#abc").val('2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.prop()` to set its value properly.

Try,

```
if (result === '1'){
    $("#abc option[value='1']").prop('selected',true);
}
else{
    $("#abc option[value='2']").prop('selected',true);
}
```

and your select's option tag should contain an attribute `value` to make that valid, But you are using `val`

```
<select id= 'abc'>
    <option value=1>a</option>
    <option value=2>b</option>
</select>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rsm93/1/)

Answer (score 1):

in html

```
<select id="abc">
    <option val="1">a</option>
    <option val="2">b</option>
</select>
```

and in javascript

```
if (result == 1){
    $("#abc").val(1);
} else {
    $("#abc").val(2);
}
```

it should work with 101% guarantee

Answer (score 0):

First of all try giving an alert for result variable which represents your ajax response. I believe it is in string format. Try using below code:

```
if (result == "1"){//compare result with string
$("#abc").val('a')
}
else  $("#abc").val('b')
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsm93/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="abc">
    <option val="1">a</option>
    <option val="2">b</option>
</select>
```

try this